# Generic Wild Card 'Super'

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard

I just read topics about generic wild card. "?", "extends", and "super" from SCJP 6 book. My question is related to method declaration using super and extends.

```
class A {
}
class B extends A {
}
class C extends B {
}
class D extends C {
}

public class Class_1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {       
         List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();
         List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();
         List<C> cs = new ArrayList<C>();
         List<D> ds = new ArrayList<D>();
         Class_1 class_1 = new Class_1();
         class_1.getName3(ds);
         class_1.getName4(bs);
         class_1.getName1(cs);
         class_1.getName2(as);
    }

    public void getName3(List<? extends B> list)
    {
    }
    public void getName4(List<? super B> list)
    {
    }
    public <T extends B> void getName1(List<T> list)
    {   
    }
    public <T super B> void getName2(List<T> list)
    {       
    }
}
```

I am getting compilation error at class_1.getName2(as);. Why ? Error is saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method getName2(List<T>) from the type Class_1 refers to the missing type T

    at com.ksh.scjp.gNc.Class_1.main(Class_1.java:26)
```

Comment: You have no wildcards in your example code...

Comment: public <T extends B> void getName1(List<T> list) and public <T super B> void getName2(List<T> list).

Comment: Those aren't wildcards.

Comment: To clarify @OliverCharlesworth's comment, `?` is a wildcard. `extends` and `super` are called *bounds*.

Comment: You could remove `getName1`, `getName3`, `getName4`, `bs`, `cs`, `ds`, `C` and `D` as they're not relevant to your question. (Then also make `getName2` static and remove `class_1`).

Comment: @immibis Please write comment if you are sure.

Comment: ? I did write a comment (saying which parts of your code are unnecessary).

Comment: @immibis so if I do that my code will work. Is that are you saying ? because its not. And it doesn't make any sense to make method static.